# Decrease the number of joins to the same parent table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have an user table containing user info and a signature table which maps to  user table with userid, as shown below

```
    users
      userid | firstname | lastname
        1   |   John       | P
        2   |   Pete       | C
        3   |   Tim        | D
```

```
  signs
     doneBy | CheckedBy | VerifiedBy
       1    |   2       | 3
```

Is there a better way to do this instead of multiple joins as below,
considering I would have 6 such joins

```
    select 
      concat(usr1.firstname, ' ', usr1.lastname) as doneby,
      concat(usr2.firstname, ' ', usr2.lastname) as checkedby,
      concat(usr3.firstname, ' ', usr3.lastname) as verifiedby
    from signs sgn
      join users usr1 on ( usr1.userid = sgn.doneBy)  
      join users usr2 on ( usr2.userid = sgn.checkedBy)  
      join users usr3 on ( usr3.userid = sgn.verifiedBy)
```

Comment: Why do you care? Do you have millions of rows in your tables?

Comment: What do you mean by what do you care? A) learning and B) its always better to use as least resources as possible! @DirkHorsten

Comment: Your time to program is a resource too, and more important your successors time to understand it is a resource. Sagi's answer got my upvote, but if all tables have less than a hundred of rows, the cost of writing it exceeds the cost of executing yours. Then I advice not to use it.

Comment: @DirkHorsten, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, but you can certainly check  the rubber on it. Yes, this table is soon going to touch millions of records, now at least you there is another way to do it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.doneBy = t.userId THEN t.full_name END) AS doneBy,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.CheckedBy = t.userId THEN t.full_name END) AS doneBy,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.VerifiedBy = t.userId THEN t.full_name END) AS doneBy
FROM (
     SELECT u.userid,concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as full_name,u.*
     FROM signs s
     INNER JOIN users u
      ON(s.userid IN(s.doneBy,s.CheckedBy,s.VerifiedBy))) t
GROUP BY t.doneBy,t.checkBy,t.VerifiedBy
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sagi let me check on this.

Comment: the query worked man, I have updated your answer to running query, thanks for the help